# Emgu CV C# Capture method RetrieveBgrFrame returns null with 4 cameras

Tags: c#, opencv, camera, emgucv

I tried to display videos from 4 cameras using the Emgu CV framework. Only the first 2 cameras were displayed properly, for the other 2, the method RetrieveBgrFrame (of the Capture objects) always return null.

I tried swap the pluging order of the camera in the usb hub, always only the first two cameras in the list obtained by DirectShow are working). To make sure all cameras working I used another commercial programs to check, all cameras are working fine.

Have any body ever experienced this? Do you know what the cause is?

Any help or pointer to help is highly appreciated.

Please help!

Thanks,

TC

======== code ==========

//--------------- creating camera objects ---------------------------

```
DsDevice[] _SystemCamereas = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice); ///// after this statement, _SystemCamereas contains 4 entries

            //Capture capture;
            Capture capture;
            capture = new Capture(2); ///// if I use '0' or '1', i.e. the ids of the first 2 cameras, picture box displayed correctly
            capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
            _captureImageBoxDict.Add(capture, imageBox1);
            imageBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

// ----------Callback method to process frame after Grab

```
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Capture capture = (Capture)sender;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame(); // for camera id = 0 or 1, frame is not null and everythins goes smoothly, for id = 2 or 3, frame is null!!!!

        if (frame == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        // ......
     }
```

========== Other system info ====================

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013

Emgu CV version: 2.4.10.1939 (acquired through Visual Studio NuGet Manager)

.NET Framework 4.5

OS: Windows 7 Professional

Processor: Intel Core i7 CPU Q 720 @ 1.60GHz

Installed memory (RAM): 16.0 GB

Comment: May be a weird question, but are all the cameras the same model? I was using 4 cameras but I could only ever get 2 working (I had 2 of the same camera and then 2 more that were both different). When I got 2 more of the first type, so I had 4 matching webcams, emgu was able to connect to all of them.

Comment: By the way, I have no idea why that happened to me. I simply know that with the same model, I was able to get all 4 cameras working simultaneously.

Comment: Did you find any solution?